# Grooming instanced curves

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances, conversion

Is there a way to convert instanced path curves into hair curves?

[image: Instanced curves]

Comment: yes, it's possible. You need to use a *Realize Instances* node to make the instances real curves. It's Nurb curves in your example. I recomment to convert them into Bezier curves first. Once you have these cuves you can convert them into a mesh (edges only) with a *Curve to Mesh* node without a Profile input. Now, you can apply the GN modifier and you have a hair mesh. Finally, you can convert this mesh into a *Curve* object (menu Object > Convert To)  and then again to a *Curves* object (=Catmull Rom curves, the hair curves).

Comment: Don't forget to increase the *Curve > Additional Subdivisions* to 2 in the render settings to smooth the hair curves and set *Curves > Shape* to *Strip*. The hair strands are probably very huge now but you can use a GN modifier to set the *Curve Radius* to something small like 0.005.